# Couldn't find package git

Tags: git

So I am trying to install git with the following command as listed on the git Linux download page:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

After that command I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done   
E: Couldn't find package git
```

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 (as that is the recommended version for Android build environment).

I am pretty new to Linux so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Okay so took a spare hard drive and installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS this morning. Ran the same command as before: sudo apt-get install git. Git install with no problem. I am guessing at this point that the most current version of git is not available for 10.04.

Comment: Which mirror are you using? It may be out of date perhaps? Also, did you run apt-get update prior to trying the install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `sudo apt-get install git-core`.